# Enable one checkbox at a time in angular2

Tags: typescript, angular2-template

I am generating multiple checkboxes dynamically using ngFor. But here i need to enable one checkbox at a time, **if one is checked the other checkboxes need to be disabled. Similarly if i uncheck the checkbox other checkboxes need to be enabled**. How to achieve this in angular2?

```
<div class="col-12 mb-2" *ngFor="let option of question.options; let i = index;">
<input type="checkbox"
       [(ngModel)]="question.options[i].correct"
       [disabled]="!question.options[i].correct && i != activeIndex"
       (ngModelChange)="copyQuestionmarks(i)">
</div>
```

In the code i am disabling the checkbox if its not a correct option and if that is not the active index. This works only for the first time, Suppose if i uncheck this other checkboxes won't get enabled.

Below is my .ts code

```
public copyQuestionmarks(i: number) {
  this.activeIndex = i;
}
```

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

in your component:

```
public copyQuestionmarks(i: number) {
  this.activeIndex = this.activeIndex === i ? i : undefined;
}
```

and in the template:

```
[disabled]="!question.options[i].correct && i !== activeIndex"
```

Explanation: The activeIndex is set every time you check the box, but you never reset the activeIndex. In the template we also need for the type of the activeIndex, because index `0 != undefined` would return false.
I am sure  there is even a much cleaner solution for those checkboxes.

Further more you don't have to write `question.options[i].correct` u can also archive the same effect by using `option.correct`, that was initalized in the ngfor loop before.